# Как сделать перенаправление на загружаемый файл? (загрузка файла по любому имени обращения)

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Имеется директория с файлом `files/default.txt`.

Файл загружается с сервера (в моем случае localhost) по ссылке `<a href="/files/default.txt" download>readme</a>`

Пытаюсь с помощью `.htaccess` реализовать загрузку файла *default.txt* при любом обращении к директории, в том числе по несуществующему имени файла, например, *readme.txt*:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch "files/(.*\.txt)$" "http://localhost/files/$1"
```

и получаю ошибку загрузки: `Ошибка: Ошибка сети.`

Прошу подсказать, что нужно исправить и почему ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вместо **.htaccess** в корне сайта добавить такой **.htaccess** в папку **files**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /files/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . default.txt [L]
</IfModule>
```